# Bootstrap 3 - Customize column width for a responsive table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

We are using Bootstrap 3.3.5. I'm trying to set different width for different columns, but the column width is setting according to the max width of table data.

I tried setting width via css, but still the width of column is adjusting to the max width of table data.

[image]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="chapter-table" class="table table-hover chapters-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sourcechapter">
                    <i id="select-all" class="fa fa-check-square-o toggle-control" data-ng-click="pubModel.selectAll()" title="Select all"></i>
                    <i id="deselect-all" class="fa fa-square-o toggle-control" data-ng-click="pubModel.deSelectAll()" title="Deselect all"></i>
                </th>
                <th class="chapterNo">
                    <a class="order-column" href="" data-ng-click="pubModel.methodCall('itemId')">
                        <span id="selectItemId">Chapter No.</span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th class="chapterTitle">
                    <a class="order-column" href="" data-ng-click="pubModel.methodCall('creatorType')">
                        <span>Chapter Title</span>
                    </a>
                </th>

                <th class="Authors">
                    <a class="order-column" href="" data-ng-click="pubModel.methodCall('names')">
                        <span>names</span>
                    </a>

                </th>
               .....
                ....                   
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="chapterDomain in chapterDomainResponse>
                <td class="assign checkbox checkbox-primary" id="checkbox-align">
                    <input class="checkbox-align" id="checkbox-{{chapterDomain.chapterNumber}}" type="checkbox" data-ng-checked="pubModel.selectedchapterDomains.indexOf(chapterDomain.chapterNumber) > -1" data-ng-click="pubModel.toggleSelectchapterDomain(chapterDomain.chapterNumber)">
                    <label for="checkbox-{{chapterDomain.chapterNumber}}"></label>
                </td>
                <td data-ng-click="pubModel.clickAction(chapterDomain.chapterNumber)" data-ng-bind="chapterDomain.col1TestData"></td>
               .......
                <td data-ng-click="pubModel.clickAction(chapterDomain.chapterNumber)" data-ng-bind="chapterDomain.col1"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <pagination total-items="pubModel.chapterPagination.totalItems" ng-model="pubModel.chapterPagination.currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="10" max-size="10"></pagination>
</div>
```